# How do you interpret the derivative of a scalar with respect to a matrix?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

For example, I can interpret the derivative of a scalar with respect to a vector (the gradient) as the direction of greatest rate of change. How do I interpret the matrix?

Comment: By stacking the columns of a matrix into a long vector, you can continue to think of the gradient in exactly the same way. The next mental trick is to reshape that gradient vector back into a matrix with the same shape as the original matrix. At that point, there's no need to keep using the vectorization/de-vectorization facade, and start thinking in terms of matrix-directions.

Comment: It's still a gradient. Just use the Frobenius inner product instead of the standard one.